# mongodb java driver spatial query

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongodb query:

```
db.location.find( { loc :
                  { $geoWithin :
                    { $centerSphere :
                       [ [ 60 , -60 ] , 50 / 3963.2 ]
                } } } ).limit(5)
```

I have tried writing this using mongodb's Java driver, but it will not work. How do we write a spatial query in Java for mongodb (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver-async/getting-started/quick-tour/)

Comment: plz share sample data of  _location_ collection. Nothing is returned by the query or any error is shown?

Comment: The data simply has lat and long, so like lat:50.8555, long:120.648 for example. The query returns data in a mongidb ahell. But I want to execute the query inside ofy java program so I am using the java driver but the problem is I can't find instructions on how to use the driver with such a query. For example where do I put $geowithin and $centersphere